# Адекватный способ добавления / скрытия массивов строк в DatagridView по checkBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется DGW с 2мя столбцами. | Имя | Количество|

Есть массив строк с Мужскими и массив с Женскими именами. Ими мы заполняем один общий DGW.

Пользователь вводит нужное количество напротив имен. 
По сохранению получаем файл.txt где 4 строки с Олегом, потом 9 строк Никит итд.
Есть чекбоксы , показать\скрыть Все мужские\женские.

Я делаю так.
При каждом CheckedChanged я сохраняю в string name [Имя, количество].(Сохраняем для того, чтобы можно было потом показать список с уже присвоенным именам значением)

Потом Foreach (DGW row in DGW.Row) и удаляю все строки которые содержат имена из сохраненного массива. 
Ну и потом я их прибавляю, таким же способом, когда cheked.

Как данную задачу выполнить с использованием лучших практик?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начать нужно с проектирования *моделей*. Создадим класс, описывающий человека. Он имеет имя, пол и количество. Пол определяется перечислением.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Sex Sex { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public enum Sex
{
    Female,
    Male
}
```

Класс формы:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

namespace WinFormApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView;
        List<Person> people;
        CheckBox checkBoxFemale;
        CheckBox checkBoxMale;
        Button buttonSave;

        public Form1()
        {
            Width = 500;
            dataGridView = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
            checkBoxFemale = new CheckBox { Parent = this, Top = dataGridView.Bottom + 20, Text = "Show Females", Checked = true };
            checkBoxMale = new CheckBox { Parent = this, Top = dataGridView.Bottom + 20, Left = 130, Text = "Show Males", Checked = true };
            buttonSave = new Button { Parent = this, Top = checkBoxFemale.Bottom + 20, Text = "Save" };

            people = new List<Person>
                {
                    new Person{ Name="Вася", Sex=Sex.Male },
                    new Person{ Name="Маша", Sex=Sex.Female },
                    new Person{ Name="Коля", Sex=Sex.Male },
                    new Person{ Name="Даша", Sex=Sex.Female },
                    new Person{ Name="Вова", Sex=Sex.Male },
                    new Person{ Name="Лена", Sex=Sex.Female },
                };

            dataGridView.DataSource = people;
            checkBoxFemale.CheckedChanged += CheckBoxSex_CheckedChanged;
            checkBoxMale.CheckedChanged += CheckBoxSex_CheckedChanged;
            buttonSave.Click += ButtonSave_Click;
        }

        private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(people, Formatting.Indented, new StringEnumConverter());
            File.WriteAllText("people.json", json);
        }

        private void CheckBoxSex_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var result = people.Where(p =>
                checkBoxFemale.Checked && p.Sex == Sex.Female ||
                checkBoxMale.Checked && p.Sex == Sex.Male);

            dataGridView.DataSource = result.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь прямо в коде заполняется коллекция с данными о людях. Она привязывается к гриду.

Нажимая на чекбоксы можно выбирать, какой пол показывать.

Ну и для примера я сделал сохранение всей коллекции (нефильтрованной) в виде json. Для этого подключите пакет

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Думаю, это даст вам толчок в нужном направлении: использование классов-моделей (а не строк), привязка коллекций, сохранение данных в общепринятом формате (используя распространённую библиотеку).

Надеюсь, будет несложно сделать сохранение фильтрованных данных (если нужно). И загрузку данных (`File.ReadAllText` + `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`).

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего собрать сроки с данными в какую-нибудь коллекцию. И через LINQ оттуда брать в зависимости от условий.